# Naming parquet files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet

I am unloading the data to S3 using unload query in redshift(File Format: Parquet).Is it possible to name the parquet files while unloading the data to S3 bucket using unload query(including partition by clause)?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `UNLOAD` is:

```
UNLOAD ('select-statement')
TO 's3://object-path/name-prefix'
...
```

Thus, you can specify a `name-prefix` that will appear at the start of the names, in the form of:

```
<object-path>/<name-prefix><slice-number>_part_<part-number>
```